# how to attach pdf files to web api http post using C#

Tags: http-post, webapi

How to attach multiple PDF files to web api http post method using C# .Trying a new logic to attach multiple PDF files in HTTP POST method WEB API using C#.Looking for a way to attach multiple PDF files in the web api response. Looking for the finest approach.